# Trying to serve dhcp inside cisco AP with mbssid

Tags: cisco, vlan, cisco-wireless

I've been following several guides online to setup a Cisco Aironet 1602I.
This AP has 2 radio anthenas and is able to produce several SSIDs via mbssid cisco configuration. My goal is to have 2 different SSIDs on the same radio and have them be separate networks, particularly, I want the second one to be isolated.

For this purpose I've followed guide on setting up different multiple SSIDs using VLANs. On VLAN1 I'm passing all the data to a different router to serve DHCP and routing to other networks (this part is actually not a problem); and for VLAN2 I want to serve DHCP directly from the AP itself.

I've done enough as to configure the SSIDs with their own networks, assign each of them to VLAN1 and VLAN2, and clients are able to see them. Clients are only able to connect to VLAN1.

VLAN1 is working without issues. Clients get DHCP from the main router (not the AP) and ping the other networks, etc. VLAN2 though seems to be dropping all packets that arrive to it and doesn't serve DHCP addresses even though we've configured a dhcp pool for it.

I'm out of ideas since all of the guides I've found seem to serve the configuration of SSIDs that don't provide DHCP directly from the AP.

I also may have done a bad job explaining the issue so apologies for any confusing part.

One of the guides below, although most of the ones online have overall the same steps:
http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/wireless-mobility/service-set-identifier-ssid/116118-configure-ap-ssid-ios.html

Current Config:

```
ap1#sh ru
Building configuration...

version 15.3
hostname ap1
!
!
no aaa new-model
no ip source-route
no ip cef
ip domain name example.com
ip dhcp excluded-address 172.16.0.1 172.16.0.20
!
ip dhcp pool guest-wifi
 import all
 network 172.16.0.0 255.255.255.0
 default-router 172.16.0.1 
 dns-server 4.2.2.2 
!
!
!
dot11 vlan-name GUEST vlan 2
dot11 vlan-name MAIN vlan 1
!
dot11 ssid TestNetwork
   vlan MAIN
   authentication open 
   authentication key-management wpa version 2
   mbssid guest-mode
   wpa-psk ascii 7 123456789
!
dot11 ssid TestNetwork 5GHz
   authentication open 
   authentication key-management wpa version 2
   guest-mode
   wpa-psk ascii 7 123456789
!
dot11 ssid TestingWiFi
   vlan GUEST
   authentication open 
   authentication key-management wpa version 2
   mbssid guest-mode
   wpa-psk ascii 7 123456789
!
!
bridge irb
interface Dot11Radio0
 no ip address
 !
 encryption mode ciphers aes-ccm 
 !
 encryption vlan GUEST mode ciphers aes-ccm 
 !
 encryption vlan MAIN mode ciphers aes-ccm 
 !
 broadcast-key change 300
 !
 !        
 ssid TestNetwork
 !
 ssid TestingWiFi
 !
 antenna gain 0
 stbc
 beamform ofdm
 mbssid
 station-role root
 rts threshold 512
 rts retries 128
 no dot11 extension aironet
!
interface Dot11Radio0.1
 encapsulation dot1Q 1 native
 bridge-group 1
 bridge-group 1 subscriber-loop-control
 bridge-group 1 spanning-disabled
 bridge-group 1 block-unknown-source
 no bridge-group 1 source-learning
 no bridge-group 1 unicast-flooding

interface Dot11Radio0.2
 encapsulation dot1Q 2
 bridge-group 2
 bridge-group 2 subscriber-loop-control
 bridge-group 2 spanning-disabled
 bridge-group 2 block-unknown-source
 no bridge-group 2 source-learning
 no bridge-group 2 unicast-flooding
!
interface Dot11Radio1
 no ip address
 !
 encryption mode ciphers aes-ccm 
 !
 broadcast-key change 300
 !
 !
 ssid TestNetwork 5GHz
 !
 antenna gain 0
 peakdetect
 no dfs band block
 stbc
 beamform ofdm
 channel dfs
 station-role root
 rts threshold 512
 rts retries 128
 no dot11 extension aironet
 bridge-group 1
 bridge-group 1 subscriber-loop-control
 bridge-group 1 spanning-disabled
 bridge-group 1 block-unknown-source
 no bridge-group 1 source-learning
 no bridge-group 1 unicast-flooding
!
interface GigabitEthernet0
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0.1
 encapsulation dot1Q 1 native
 bridge-group 1
 bridge-group 1 spanning-disabled
 bridge-group 1 block-unknown-source
 no bridge-group 1 source-learning
!
interface GigabitEthernet0.2
 encapsulation dot1Q 2
 bridge-group 2
 bridge-group 2 spanning-disabled
 bridge-group 2 block-unknown-source
 no bridge-group 2 source-learning
!         
interface BVI1
 mac-address xxxx.xxxx.xxxx
 ip address 192.168.1.30 255.255.255.128
 ipv6 address dhcp
 ipv6 address autoconfig
 ipv6 enable
!
interface BVI2
 mac-address xxxx.xxxx.xxxx
 ip address 172.16.0.30 255.255.255.0
 ip information-reply
 history PPS
!
ip default-gateway 192.168.1.1
ip forward-protocol nd
bridge 1 priority 1
bridge 1 protocol ieee
bridge 1 route ip
bridge 2 priority 10
bridge 2 protocol ieee
bridge 2 route ip
```

Comment: Provide your config.

Comment: How is the switch port that the AP connects to configured?